# Is there a Rust Result method like expect but which propagates the error instead of panicking?

Tags: rust

You can unwrap a `Result` (panic on `Err`) with a custom message using `expect`.
How can you propagate an error with a custom message (rather than the default message with `?`)?

```rust
use std::io::{Result, Error, ErrorKind};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let a = Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::other, "default message"));
    // Let's pretend a is a result automatically created by some other method.
    
    let b = a.unwrap();                  // panics with default message
    let b = a.expect("custom message");  // panics with custom message
    
    let b = a?;                          // Returns Err with default message
    let b = /* What goes here? */        // Returns Err with custom message
}
```

Comment: [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)

Comment: @EvilTak Also, how can I just use a string for my error?

Comment: @asdf3.14159 you can use `Err("my error message".into())`, which will do the job if you are short on time. If you are not however, you can consider using a crate such as [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/) for creating your errors as `enum`s, and having them nicely organized. Of course, strum offers way more besides the things I mentioned. Another option would be to create the `enum`s without the mentioned crate and just implement the [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait for the error manually from the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to handle this.  First, recognize that there is no standard "custom error message" in this context, because in `Result<T, E>`, the `E` type can be *any type at all,* even one that doesn't implement `std::error::Error`.  So, the analogy to the panicking methods doesn't exactly hold.  In particular, note that `a?` **does not** return "`Err` with default message!"  (See below for an explanation.)  What you might be looking for instead is a mechanism to convert from one error type to another.

One way to do this is with [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err), which maps one error value to another.

```
struct ErrorA;
struct ErrorB;

fn foo() -> Result<(), ErrorA> { todo!() }

fn example() -> Result<(), ErrorB> {
    let a = foo();
    
    let b = a.map_err(|_| ErrorB);
    
    b
}
```

However, you can make this automatic by realizing that `?` operator performs [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)-based conversion of the error.  The expression `a?` is roughly equivalent to:

```
match a {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return Err(std::convert::Into::into(e)),
}
```

This means it will automatically convert between error types if a suitable `Into` impl exists.  For example:

```
struct ErrorA;
struct ErrorB;

impl From<ErrorA> for ErrorB {
    fn from(_: ErrorA) -> Self { Self }
}

fn foo() -> Result<(), ErrorA> { todo!() }

fn example() -> Result<(), ErrorB> {
    let a = foo();
    
    let b = a?; // Conversion to ErrorB is implicit
    
    Ok(b)
}
```

If you really want just a "custom string" error then you can use `String` or `&'static str` as the error type.  This can be problematic in some contexts though, because neither of these types implement `std::error::Error`.  However, there is a conversion from both to `Box<dyn Error>`, so if you don't want to define your own error type you can do something like:

```
struct ErrorA;

fn foo() -> Result<(), ErrorA> { todo!() }

fn example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let a = foo();
    
    // ? converts the &str to Box<dyn Error>
    let b = a.map_err(|_| "custom error message")?;
    
    Ok(b)
}
```

This approach is suitable for simple Rust programs, but generally shouldn't be used in Rust libraries.  Custom error types are more suitable for libraries as they allow callers to distinguish different failure scenarios.

---

Further reading:

- [The Rust Programming Language - Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)

Comment: What is the best error type to use in the result returned from the `main` function? I want the error to be displayed to the user.

Comment: @asdf3.14159 Anything implementing `Error` that captures all of the possible error types your program can return from `main`. `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` is a pretty straightforward "set it and forget it" return type for `main`.

Comment: How could I display an error message with `eprintln!` and then return from main cleanly with an error code, but without displaying a returned error to the user?

Comment: @asdf3.14159 Maybe [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df4cc31cffbab3570e9cee46b6501f20)? This is a pattern I use a lot. `run` becomes your `main`. The `Ok` case returns an exit code (0 is standard for success, so typically you'll return `Ok(0)`). On an error, the error is displayed and the exit code is set to 1 (standard for some kind of failure).

Comment: @asdf3.14159 [This example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=feb31a306c38273f58ef32e7bd8937ae) might be more in line with modern Rust, actually. `run` should return `Ok(ExitCode::SUCCESS)` normally.